# Histogram function imhist() produces a white line with black dots

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I want to see the histogram of an image using the built in function `imhist()` but instead of giving me the expected histogram I am presented with a straight white line.

This is the test image which I am using to create a histogram: http://tenettech.com/content/images/thumbs/0002817_basys2_spartan_3e_250k_gates_fpga_board_600.jpeg

This is the code I am using to get my histogram:

```
img = imread('test.jpg');
gray = rgb2gray(img);
hist = imhist(gray);
imshow(hist);
```

This is what I get from `imshow(hist);`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqnlb.jpg

Its difficult to see properly but with a gray background it is just a white line with the black spot at top.

I was expecting a result like this: http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/graphiac.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of [imhist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html) is a vector of counts, not an image (i.e., displaying this 1D vector of numbers as an image through `imshow` will produce the "black-dots line").

Either use `plot` (or `bar`) to display the histogram OR use `imhist` without any output arguments to get a (default) histogram plot.

```
nBins = 100; % 
[counts, x] = imhist(gray, nBins);
figure; bar(x, counts);

figure; imhist(gray, nBins)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just directly use:

```
img = imread('test.jpg');
gray = rgb2gray(img);
figure,imhist(gray)
figure, bar(imhist(img))
figure,bar(imhist(img,50))
```

Comment: Thanks but in ``figure, bar(imhist(I))`` what does ``I`` represent?